# How I can list all the unique values from my XML using XSL 1 and how to achieve the same in XSL 2?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Ok, so I m knew to XSLT and for practicing I downloaded a data set from gov uk websites. I m working on a set of data about hygiene ratings in food industry in Brighton and Hove UK.

**My XML data file looks like this...** but is much longer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "test5.xsl"?> 
<FHRSEstablishment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Header>
                <ExtractDate>2018-01-13</ExtractDate>
                <ItemCount>3074</ItemCount>
                <ReturnCode>Success</ReturnCode>
            </Header>
                <EstablishmentCollection>
                    <EstablishmentDetail>
                        <FHRSID>736377</FHRSID>
                        <LocalAuthorityBusinessID>2014/00302/COMM</LocalAuthorityBusinessID>
                        <BusinessName>16</BusinessName>
                        <BusinessType>Restaurant/Cafe/Canteen</BusinessType>
                        <BusinessTypeID>1</BusinessTypeID>
                        <AddressLine1>16 Sydney Street</AddressLine1>
                        <AddressLine2>Brighton</AddressLine2>
                        <PostCode>BN1 4EN</PostCode>
                        <RatingValue>5</RatingValue>
                        <RatingKey>fhrs_5_en-GB</RatingKey>
                        <RatingDate>2017-01-12</RatingDate>
                        <LocalAuthorityCode>875</LocalAuthorityCode>
                        <LocalAuthorityName>Brighton and Hove</LocalAuthorityName>
                        <LocalAuthorityWebSite>http://www.brighton-hove.gov.uk/foodsafety</LocalAuthorityWebSite>
                        <LocalAuthorityEmailAddress>ehl.food@brighton-hove.gov.uk</LocalAuthorityEmailAddress>
                            <Scores>
                                <Hygiene>0</Hygiene>
                                <Structural>0</Structural>
                                <ConfidenceInManagement>0</ConfidenceInManagement>
                            </Scores>
                        <SchemeType>FHRS</SchemeType>
                        <NewRatingPending>False</NewRatingPending>
                            <Geocode>
                                <Longitude>-0.13802900000000</Longitude>
                                <Latitude>50.82747700000000</Latitude>
                            </Geocode>
                    </EstablishmentDetail>
                    <EstablishmentDetail>
                        <FHRSID>722916</FHRSID>
                        <LocalAuthorityBusinessID>2014/00536/COMM</LocalAuthorityBusinessID>
                        <BusinessName>18 Grocery</BusinessName>
                        <BusinessType>Retailers - other</BusinessType>
                        <BusinessTypeID>4613</BusinessTypeID>
                        <AddressLine1>Unit 18</AddressLine1>
                        <AddressLine2>Open Market</AddressLine2>
                        <AddressLine3>Marshalls Row</AddressLine3>
                        <AddressLine4>Brighton</AddressLine4>
                        <PostCode>BN1 4JU</PostCode>
                        <RatingValue>4</RatingValue>
                        <RatingKey>fhrs_4_en-GB</RatingKey>
                        <RatingDate>2014-12-01</RatingDate>
                        <LocalAuthorityCode>875</LocalAuthorityCode>
                        <LocalAuthorityName>Brighton and Hove</LocalAuthorityName>
                        <LocalAuthorityWebSite>http://www.brighton-hove.gov.uk/foodsafety</LocalAuthorityWebSite>
                        <LocalAuthorityEmailAddress>ehl.food@brighton-hove.gov.uk</LocalAuthorityEmailAddress>
                            <Scores>
                                <Hygiene>0</Hygiene>
                                <Structural>5</Structural>
                                <ConfidenceInManagement>10</ConfidenceInManagement>
                            </Scores>
                        <SchemeType>FHRS</SchemeType>
                        <NewRatingPending>False</NewRatingPending>
                            <Geocode>
                                <Longitude>-0.13602300000000</Longitude>
                                <Latitude>50.83150100000000</Latitude>
                            </Geocode>
                    </EstablishmentDetail>
                </EstablishmentCollection>
 </FHRSEstablishment>
```

What I m interested in here is to list all the unique / distinct values for **RatingValue** to find out all possible options.

I have been researching and trying all sort of different methods but nothing seems to work for me. All other examples are based on simpler XML's data and I struggle to filter through my file.

The code I come up with for **XSL 1.0** is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>  

 <xsl:key name="stars" match="/FHRSEstablishment/EstablishmentCollection/*" use="name()" /> 

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/FHRSEstablishment/EstablishmentCollection/*
    [count(. | key('stars', name())[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="name()" />
        <xsl:value-of select="RatingValue" />
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output I m getting is just one number **5**

I know there is only 5 posiible ratings from 1 - 5 but I d like to find this using XSL and display the results.
I also tried this code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>  

 <xsl:key name="stars" match="/FHRSEstablishment/EstablishmentCollection/*" use="name()" /> 

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/FHRSEstablishment/EstablishmentCollection/*
    [count(. | key('stars', name())[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="name()" />
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but output here that I m getting is:
**EstablishmentDetail**

Can someone please help and explained to me how I can achieve that in XSL 1.0 using "key"and using distinct-value function in xsl 2?

Comment: Well, the function is named `distinct-values` and if you want to select all `RatingValue` elements you use `//RatingValue` and to apply the function you simply use `distinct-values(//RatingValue)` which could then be output in XSLT 2 or later using `<xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(//RatingValue)"/>`.

Comment: still can't get it to show values :(

Comment: I tried with for-each and without it and nothing :(
`<h2>Brighton &amp; Hove Restaurant Hygiene Ratings</h2>     <xsl:for-each select="/FHRSEstablishment/EstablishmentCollection/EstablishmentDetail"> <li><xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(//RatingValue)"/></li></xsl:for-each>`

Comment: At http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWV6 you can see the result of my suggestion on the sample you posted.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinHonnen makes sens. I m doing it in text editor and trying to check it on firefox/chrome/ie and there it doesnt work. I guess I need some plugins or move it to proper IDE

Comment: @PeterPan, the default XPath engines provided by firefox, chrome, etc still only support XPath 1.0, which does not provide the distinct-values() function.

Comment: @MichaelKay so there is no way to just ope XML in a browser and get desire results using xsl and functions as distinct-value() ?

Comment: @PeterPan ... use a dedicated [XSLT 2.0 processor](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) (i.e., Saxon). Browsers are only useful for HTML rendered XSLT 1.0 outputs.

Comment: @PeterPan sadly that is correct. The browser vendors lost interest in XML and its user community years ago. You need third-party plugins (such as Saxon-JS) for anything but the most basic functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **XSLT 1.0**, consider adjusting the key to the specific value, *RatingValue*, you need and then walking down the tree as opposed to `<xsl:for-each>`. Then conditionally specify to pull only those values with generated key being the first per grouping for distinct values:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>  

 <xsl:key name="stars" match="EstablishmentDetail" use="RatingValue" /> 

 <xsl:template match="/FHRSEstablishment">
   <output>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="EstablishmentCollection"/>
   </output>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="EstablishmentCollection">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="EstablishmentDetail[generate-id() = 
                                 generate-id(key('stars', RatingValue))]">
          <xsl:sort select="RatingValue" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="EstablishmentDetail">
   <rating>
      <xsl:value-of select="RatingValue"/>
   </rating>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Demo](http://xsltransform.net/nb9MWsy/1)

For **XSLT 2.0**, consider narrowing in on the parent of *RatingValue* then run `<xsl:for-each-group>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>  

 <xsl:template match="/FHRSEstablishment">
   <output>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="EstablishmentCollection"/>
   </output>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="EstablishmentCollection">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="EstablishmentDetail" group-by="RatingValue"> 
      <xsl:sort select="RatingValue"/>
      <rating>
        <xsl:value-of select="RatingValue"/>
      </rating>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Demo](http://xsltransform.net/gVrtEmu/1)

For demos, I extended your posted XML to include multiple *RatingValues* (copying element sections) of 5, 4, 4, 3. Notice 4 does not repeat in output and values are sorted.

```
<output>
  <rating>3</rating>
  <rating>4</rating>
  <rating>5</rating>
</output>
```

---

For HTML output, simply replace the `<output>` and `<rating>` tags with HTML ones:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="xsi">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="html"/>  

 <xsl:key name="stars" match="EstablishmentDetail" use="RatingValue" /> 

 <xsl:template match="/FHRSEstablishment">
   <html>
     <body>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="EstablishmentCollection"/>
     </body>
   </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="EstablishmentCollection">
    <ul>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="EstablishmentDetail[generate-id() = generate-id(key('stars', RatingValue))]">
          <xsl:sort select="RatingValue" />
       </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ul>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="EstablishmentDetail">
   <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="RatingValue"/>
   </li>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Parfait the XSL 1 solution works for me. However, the second one throws an error when I use your code, I copy and pasted to my XSL, and try to open XML file in a browser. Any idea on that? Is it something on my side?
`Error during XSLT transformation: XSLT transformation failed.`

Comment: XSL 1 solution looks nice and simple plus it deliveres the result I want and the way I was trying was with use of key and generate-id() function with no luck to get that displayed; +1 for you

Comment: Also, a quick question, where exactly do I insert HTML for XSL 1 solution to style the output it in whatever way I want e.q list, table? Thanks, @Parfait

Comment: As commented above, you cannot run XSLT 2.0 in any browser. You must use a dedicated XSLT 2.0 processor (i.e., installed .exe program). Browsers can only run XSLT 1.0. As for HTML output, replace tags in this solution (`<output><rating>`) to HTML ones. See edit.